# number of unordered pairs of integers from 1 to N which are coprime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

How many unordered pairs of integers from 1 to N are coprime?

FOR N=4,ans is 6

.for n=3,ans is 4.

FOR N=4 I MADE THESE PAIRS (1,4) (3,4) (2,1)(2,3) (1,3) SO WHAT IS THAT I AM MISSING ?

FOR N=3 I MADE THESE PAIRS (1,3) (2,3) (1,2) BUT ANSWER IS 4.

how will the answer differ if we say ordered pair of integers?

Comment: $(1,1)$ is always such a pair.

Comment: In first case you count $(3,4)$ twice.

Comment: @Abstraction EDITED

Answer (score 3):

As @lulu mentions in the comments, $1$ is coprime with $1$, so that $\{ 1,1 \}$ is such a pair.

More generally, for each $n \le N$ there are $\varphi(n)$ unordered pairs of the form $(k,n)$ with $k \le n$ and $k,n$ coprime, where $\varphi$ denotes [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). So in general the number of unordered coprime pairs of numbers less than or equal to $N$ is
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \varphi(n)$$
This agrees with your answers:

- $N=3$: $\varphi(1)+\varphi(2)+\varphi(3) = 1+1+2=4$.
- $N=4$: $\varphi(1)+\varphi(2)+\varphi(3)+\varphi(4) = 1+1+2+2=6$.